# How to fix xrandr scaling

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have two monitors side by side. One is `3840x2160@30hz` the other is `1280x1024@60hz`. I am trying to set the smaller monitor's scale:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 2x2
```

With this command only 1/4 of the monitor is usable.

How can I fix this issue with xrandr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the bug described [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39949), I had to patch and recompile the `xserver-xorg-core` package using Chris Wilson's [patch](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=94929).

Here's how I did it:

Download the source and patch for the xserver-xorg-core package.

```
mkdir src && cd src

apt-get source xorg-server

cd xorg-xserver-x.xx.x/randr

wget -O- "https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=94929" > randr.patch
```

Patch xrandr:

```
patch -p1 < randr.patch
```

At

```
File to patch:
```

type:

```
rrcrtc.c
```

Install build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-core
```

Install more build packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts fakeroot
```

Compile the package:

```
cd ..

debuild -us -uc -i -I
```

Install the new package:

```
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-core_x.xx.x-x.deb
```

Restart your DE and xrandr should now scale perfectly!

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon with a 4k monitor that requires 150% scaling to be usable, and two other 1080p monitors. I set my scaling to 150% with the Linux Mint system default display settings app, and then try to switch profiles using the RrandR gui, but scaling causes very weird screen display overlapping and swaps scaling settings across my screens. Why is this still a bug in 2023? Any way I can fix this without having to compile source and dependencies??